# jQuery each and animate not working correctly

Tags: jquery, each

I want to animate every `.item` box with delays.

I've got two problems with it:

1. I need to disable toggle while it's animating but it's very tricky with `each` because it's not working like in PHP - even if I set `bool to false` after `each` (like example below), it just runs it as many times as there are elements. Also if I use `animate()` callback - it also triggers many times.
2. I also need to add disappear animation (just reversed). Do I just copy it and reverse opacity?

---

```
var isAnimating = false;

$('.toggle').click(function() {

    //Only run it if it's not animating
    if(!isAnimating) {

        isAnimating = true;

        menu.toggleClass('open');

        item = $('.item');

        $.each($(item), function(i, el) {

            $(el).css({'opacity': 0});

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(el).toggleClass('open').animate({
                    'opacity': 1.0
                }, 450);
            },50 + ( i * 200 ));

        });

        //It just triggers it as many times as there are elements..
        isAnimating = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML and CSS you are using as well please?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/L7o1exy0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `is(':animated')` to detect the element is animationg or not.
2. For hiding the elements from last use `reverse()` function. On first click elements need to be displayed first, then run animation and vice versa on second click.

Try like following. Hope this will help you.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function () {

        var item = $('.item');

        if (item.is(':animated')) return;

        if (item.hasClass('open')) {
            $.each(item.toArray().reverse(), function(i, el) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(el).animate({
                            'opacity': 0
                        }, 450, function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('open');
                        });
                }, 50 + (i * 200));
            });
        } else {
            $.each(item, function (i, el) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(el).addClass('open').animate({
                        'opacity': 1
                    }, 450);
                }, 50 + (i * 200));
            });
        }
});
```

```css
body {
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: #222;
    }

    .toggle {
        height: 50px;
        width: 75px;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .toggle:hover {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #222;
        }

    .wrap {
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -125px;
        margin-left: -50px;
    }

    .item {
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

        .item.open {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">Toggle</div>
<div class="wrap">
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you for your time! Just a quick question: does it also detect `CSS keyframe animations` or just jQuery `animate()`?

Comment: Just jQuery `animate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a partial solution to your question. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7o1exy0/4/) solves the first part of your problem.

Here i use the `off()` method to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the click event on the selected element. Hence the need to use `on()` to bind the click event in the first place. Do refer to the api documentation for unbind that i have mentioned to to clarify about event delegation in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. You think I could use it with toggle functionality somehow? To be able to toggle it back when animation is finished?

Comment: Im trying to figure out the second part of your question. No luck yet!

Comment: Thank you. Im also trying to find something useful from jQuery docs and old SO questions.